# Flight Search using A* algorithm; suitable cost and huristic

Tags: shortest-path, a-star, preflight

I'm going to find the quickest and the cheapest flights using A* algorithm, when it is given the source and destination airports. These two paths will be found separately.

To find the quickest path , I'm going to use average travel time between the source and destination airports as the huristic value.

I have few problems:

1. could you please tell me, where can I find a data source , which has average travel times between every airport pair? Or any data source which contains the distances between every airport pair?
2. Finding the cheapest path is not easy as I thought.All the fares can not be used as a cost of an edge(flight leg is taken as an edge).Because some fares are applicable to more than one flight leg .e.g: from SFO to JFK via BOS  100$.

   2.1 Could you please suggest me a way of finding the cheapest path/paths?

   2.2 Is A* is suitable for this?

   2.3 If it is suitable what is the most appropriate huristic value to be used?

   2.4 Is there any way to get a data source containing average fare between each airport pair?

Great Help friends...
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: for some data you could scrape the site of some ex-microsoft guys http://rome2rio.com or at least contact them how they are doing it (please post your results here :))

Comment: Why is this not a real question? The more I use stackoverflow the less I understand this ...

Comment: I would add an answer, but unfortunately it's closed, so I'll just add a few comments.

Comment: First and foremost, why do you want to do this? There are several online reservation companies that provide this service and the task is extremely difficult. It is difficult, because air fares are unbelievable mess. I suspect it's actually not possible unless you are IATA member and/or have agreements with the airlines.

Comment: Not only are some fares applicable to more than one flight leg, the fare is usually unique for specific air ticket purchase including all legs, all flights, the return route, particular flight, date of flight and date of return, storno and rebooking options and availability of any customer cards. And you can't even estimate it, because the differences are often quite big.

Comment: It's unlikely you'd want to change more than 3 times on any reasonable route and it rarely make sense to book with multiple airlines and that's about it. So I suspect breadth-first search with simple pruning based on number of legs, distance and time is best you can actually get, because the fare can't be calculated before you have the whole route (in fact it can't be calculated; it must be queried from the airline-in-question's ordering system).

Answer (score 1):

Some assorted answer:

1. You probably do not need it. The speed of line aircrafts is quite consistent (as an average is around 800/900 km/h) so you can simply divide the distance by the speed and get the time. The distance can easily be obtained from any map service on the web (Google Maps, e.g.). For a better estimate, you can data-mine the web sites of operators (see below).
2. It looks like you have to use a multi-weighted edge analysis. That is: every edge will have more than one weight/cost associated to it and you will have to take all of them into account. This because the overall cost is usually the sum of many indipendent elements. The fact that the same fare is applicable to more than one flight is probably irrelevant. Just apply the same fare to all the involved flights and go on.

2.1 See above.

2.3 Most likely, you should consider "contraction hierarchy" as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchy . Have a look at OSRM: http://project-osrm.org/ .

2.4 Most likely, the only way is data-mining the web (because fares are continuosly changing).

Data-mining the web for distances, traveling time and other data is not easy and probably will require some kind of agreement with the operators. Have a look at their web site for info.

Comment: the distances could be calculated via lat,lon values from OpenStreetMaps using haversine formula.

Comment: contraction hierarchy is not about heuristics it is about improving speed of calculation. very important for road networks but I doubt this is of any use for flights (makes all a lot more complicated and the network shouldn't be that big. and the network is time dependent btw ...)

Comment: Distance is useless. The calculation has to use the actual schedule. It makes things somewhat more complicated, but not that much; the weight simply depends on the current tentative distance in the vertex.